# Set the list value on the searchfield in Sencha touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have this method on the controller

```
   onResponsibleSuggestListTap: function (list, index, target, record, event, eOpts) {
    var activityGeneral = this.getActivityGeneral();
    //set the text field value
    activityGeneral.down('#responsible').setValue(record.get('value'));
    console.log(record.get('value'));
    //hide out floating list
    this.getResponsibleSuggest().destroy();

    //clear the drop down list
    this.onClearResponsibleField();
},
```

and in the view:

```
items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    width: '60%',
                    padding: '0 3px 0 0',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'searchfield',
                            itemId: 'responsibleSearchField',
                            placeHolder: 'introduces..."
                        }
                    ]
                }
       ]
```

But I cannot set the value after the click on the item in the searchfield, what am i doing wrong??

Thanks a lot!

Comment: add "id" config in searchfield add use it in "refs" for create instance.

Comment: please, could you show any example?? I am new with sencha

Answer (score 1):

try after change as per below

```
activityGeneral.query('searchfield[itemId=responsibleSearchField]')[0].setValue(record.get('value'));
```

Comment: Now I am receiving this error: Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined

Comment: Thanks a lot Naresh, I found the solution, I was doing any wrong.. for instance, instead of xtype: searchfield was selectfield... Thanks.